# How to avoid the need to make changes on the base image and re-build the small-app container to get changes in?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two separate projects. One is the base code shared among several smaller projects and the second one is just one smaller project with updates on the UI by overriding some CSS and so on but this one does not touch React or NextJS code at all.

The following `Dockerfile` belongs to the first project:

```
FROM node:lts as builder
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm i npm@9.8.1 -g  \
    && npm install
COPY --link . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

and this is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  react-app:
    container_name: react_app
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: local/Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/app/src
      - ./app/package.json:/app/package.json
      - ./app/package-lock.json:/app/package-lock.json
    restart: unless-stopped
```

As you can see this is building a `react_app` image which I use later to build the smaller project using this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM react_app:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY --link . /app/src/styles/
COPY --link ./favicon.ico /app/public/favicon.ico
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

and this `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  small-app-1:
    container_name: small-app-1
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: react_app
    build:
        context: theme
        dockerfile: ../local/Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - "11500:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./theme:/app/src/style/theme
      - ./app/package-lock.json:/app/package-lock.json
    restart: unless-stopped
```

(cont) this process is tedious because I have to make code-level changes on the base image and then rebuild the smaller project to get those changes there.

I wonder if there is a better way to make changes to the code base for the `small-app` container. In a few words, I would like to edit the base code in the `small-app` container without the need to build the base image all the time and then re-build the `small-app` image just to get the changes in.

Can I get some ideas or suggestions?

Comment: If the changes do not need to be in the base image, why not just make the changes to your `small-app` image in the second Dockerfile?  Without a better understanding of what changes you are trying to make, I am not sure what else you are looking for.  Also, you seem to be using `image: react_app` for your `small-app`, but your post mentions building a new image.  Clarification on the second image you are building and where it is intended to be used could be helpful.